# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_sql´: how do I fix this error with my scraper?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape spells from a dnd page into a pd dataframe and convert said dataframe into a SQLite database.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
import csv
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

url1 = "http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/spells"
url_list = [url1,]

for url in url_list:


  ## Make Requests
  data = requests.get(url).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

  # Scrape all tables into a pandas df (up to this part, it works)
  df_pandas = pd.read_html(url, attrs = {'class': 'wiki-content-table'},  flavor='bs4', thousands ='.')

# converting the df into a sqlite database
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('dndata.db')
c = conn.cursor()

df_pandas.to_sql('spells', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

The last line of code gets this error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\chpap\Documents\Dokumente\Python lernen\Python book club\Cinema_Scraper\CS_Main.ipynb Cell 12 line 1
----> 1 df_pandas.to_sql('spells', conn, if_exists='replace')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_sql'
```

Could you help me pointing out and fixing my error?

I added the line `c=conn.cursor(`) because I was told that it would make Python recognize "to_sql", but the error message remains the same.

I also added the sql magic "%load_ext sql" to facilitate the smoother transition from Python to SQLITE, but it didn´t change the error message either

Comment: `pandas.read_html` [returns lis of daframe objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html). Also note that if `url_list` has more than one element, you will get only the last one, overwriting data from previous urls

Answer (score 0):

`read_html` returns list of DataFrame objects. So you need to pick up first or iterate all and invoke `to_sql` method.
Also regarding first parameter of `read_html`, it could be url or html itself.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('dndata.db')
c = conn.cursor()

for url in url_list:
    df_pandas_list = pd.read_html(url, attrs={'class': 'wiki-content-table'}, flavor='bs4', thousands='.')

    df_pandas_list[0].to_sql('spells', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `pd.concat` to concat all tables found on the website to one large dataframe:

```py
import csv
import re
import sqlite3
from random import randint
from urllib.request import urlopen

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/spells"

url_list = [
    url1,
]

all_dfs = []
for url in url_list:
    ## Make Requests
    data = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

    df_pandas = pd.concat(
        pd.read_html(
            url, attrs={"class": "wiki-content-table"}, flavor="bs4", thousands="."
        )
    )

    all_dfs.append(df_pandas)


conn = sqlite3.connect("dndata.db")
c = conn.cursor()

# iterate over all dataframes in list `all_dfs` and save them to database
for i, df in enumerate(all_dfs, 1):
    df.to_sql(f"spells_{i}", conn, if_exists="replace")
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much, it is working now